# ssh ProxyJump by using kerberos first and the keys

Tags: ssh

I have a machine `nodeA` on which I can log in with kerberos tokens.

On my laptop `.ssh/config` I have an easy

```
Host nodeA
     HostName nodeA.longdomain.com
     User pippo
     GSSAPIAuthentication            yes
     GSSAPIDelegateCredentials       yes
     ForwardX11                      yes
     ForwardX11Trusted               yes
```

And my first action in the morning is a `kinit`, so I can `ssh nodeA` easily.

I have a second machine `nodeB` that is reachable only from `nodeA`. I have ssh pub key from `nodeA:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` copied into `nodeB:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` so I can easily login from there.

Now I'd like have an entry in my laptop `.ssh/config` for `nodeB` for jumping on `nodeA` first (using KRB for authentication) and then, with the `nodeA` pub key, authenticating into `nodeB`.

```
Host nodeB
     HostName nodeB.longdomain.com
     User pipe
     ProxyJump nodeA
     ForwardX11                      yes
     ForwardX11Trusted               yes
     #some option I don't know
```

Which option should I use actually?